# Python. Ошибка os.path.splitext

Tags: python

Когда я использую данный путь(часть пути файла):
`C:\Users`
В функции
`os.path.splitext()`
То вылетает ошибка:
`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`
Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На языке Python в строках символ `\` является символом экранирования.

Например `\n` - перевод строки.

Передавая путь `C:\Users` вы, считайте, сказали интерпретатору:

> Считай мне такую строку: "C:", дальше идет символ \U, а дальше "sers".

А интерпретатор говорит:

> Но я не знаю что это за символ \U

Пишите вот так:

`C:/Users` или вот так `C:\\Users` (т.к. \ также отключает экранирования экранируемых символов)

Второй вариант применяется автоматически при использовании префикса `r` перед строкой, делающего следующую за ним строку "сырой" (игнорирующей экранируемые символы).

```py
>>> 'C:\Users'
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can not decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>>> r'C:\Users'
'C:\\Users'
```

Comment: Я честно говоря не помню как с питоном на винде работать, поэтому если один из этих вариантов не подходит, отредактируйте ответ, удалив этот вариант, пожалуйста